# What do we know about the historic Padmasambhava?

Tags: history, tibetan-buddhism

I had heard Padmasambhava referred to as a semi-mythic figure. Some of his reputed activities would fit a mythic character. However to what extent is he also a historical figure. What do we know about the historic as opposed to mythic Padmasambhava and what if any historic sources do we have about him and his activities.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padmasambhava) says, "nothing is known ... apart from him helping the construction of a temple at Samye at the behest of Trisong Detsen and shortly being chased out of Tibet."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tibetans think of Padmasambhava as the second most important person for their lineage.

http://www.dharmafellowship.org/biographies/historicalsaints/lord-padmasambhava.htm

Here is a sample from the link above - more is available for your reading or study

> There is no doubt in the mind of every practitioner of Tibetan
>   Buddhism that the second most unique and extraordinary exemplar of our
>   whole lineage after Pramodavajra himself, was the powerful Lord
>   Padmasambhava, the Wisdom Master who was chiefly instrumental in
>   bringing the tradition to Tibet. Known as the Lotus Guru (padma-guru),
>   the Saint Lama (guru Rinpoche) of Tibet, and as a "second Buddha",
>   Padmasambhava1 shines with the incomparable brightness of the morning
>   star in the world's firmament of stellar saints. Long before he was
>   born, mystics and prophets were signaling his advent. During his life
>   he drew the respect and veneration of kings and emperors and after his
>   death the multitude made his memory into an imperishable icon of the
>   Absolute.

The history offered is extensive so will let this quote be the introduction to a very long web page.